# changing html form value then submitting to webpage

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am simply trying to get the user name via an html button then append a string to it before submitting the concatenated string to a website.  But the string doesn't seem to change

```
<form action="website.com" method="POST">
<input name="login" id="name" value="username" />
<script>
    var str1 = document.getElementsById("name").value;
    var str2 = " Goodbye";
    document.getElementsById("name").value = str1.concat(str2);
</script>
<button id="button" >press the button</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing `getElementsById`, which isn't a function.

Try it singular, not plural:

```
document.getElementById("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
     <form action="website.com" method="POST">
     <input name="login" id="name" value="username" />
     </form>
     <script>
         function getName() {
            var str1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var str2 = " Goodbye";
            document.getElementById("name").value = str1.concat(str2);
         }
        </script>
        <button id="button" onclick="getName()">press the button</button>
```